# Rails 5.1 - how to pass environment vars through webpack to frontend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I would like to change the domain of my api on the frontend that makes api calls. On development I would like a localhost:xxxx domain and a separate one for staging and production. Now, the default Rails webpack dev server exposes an empty `.env` key on the `process` object.

I've tried passing this configuration both manually in `bin/webpack-dev-server` like this:

```
Dir.chdir(APP_PATH) do
  exec "NODE_PATH=#{NODE_MODULES_PATH} #{WEBPACK_BIN} --progress --color " \
    "--config #{DEV_SERVER_CONFIG} NODE_ENV=development #{ARGV.join(" ")}"
end
```

I've also tried to add on to the `.env` object directly in `config/shared.js` like this:

```
new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Object.assign(env, { 'NODE_ENV': process.ev)))),
```

Both of those approaches don't modify the `.env` object.

Ideas?

*Solution*

Ditch using webpack as a way to pass environmental variables. Assign an environment variable on the `window` object using good old Rails environment.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working by using a [webpack environment plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/):

```
// config/webpack/development.js

const webpack = require('webpack')
const environment = require('./environment')
const config = environment.toWebpackConfig()

config.plugins = (config.plugins || []).concat([
  new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin([ 'SECRET_KEY' ])
])

module.exports = config
```

In your app, you should be able to access `SECRET_KEY` inside process.env:

```
console.log(process.env.SECRET_KEY)
```

Hope that helps!